# How can I make prevent the code from crashing when the user inputs nothing in the function

Tags: python

When I use the function, `def problem1_5(age)`, and instead of inputting a value for age, I run the code, it crashes. How can I improve the code so when I dont input any value for age, it doesn't crash

This is for an online course i am undertaking, and I've already tried putting in a if at the beginning of the code statement but it could be possible that I did it inaccurately.

```
def problem1_5(age):
    if age < 7:
        print ("have a glass of milk")
    elif age < 21:
        print ("have a coke")
    else:
        print ("Have a martini")
```

I expect, when I enter nothing, to take me to another line or maybe end the code, but it just crashes.

Comment: Where in the code you input value for `age`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

Add a default value for the input argument.

```
def problem1_5(age=999):
    if age < 7:
        print ("have a glass of milk")
    elif age < 21:
        print ("have a coke")
    else:
        print ("Have a martini")
```

Now age is 999, unless another value is assigned to it.

Comment: thank you very much, just one question, why doesnt it output "have a martini" since it technically falls into the else catagory

Comment: It does for me! Put a print statement "print(age)" right after "def problem1_5(age=999):" and see what is the value of "age" when you call "problem1_5".